# Trouble with printing parent state from child (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to use a parent to control an editor component and a save component. The parent component has these functions:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    code: "",
    current_program: 'new'
  }
}

updateCode(event) {
  this.setState({
    code: event
  });
}

save() {
  console.log(this.state.code);
}
```

In it's render component, I have this:

```
<IDE code={this.state.code} updateCode={this.updateCode}/>
<Browser save={this.save.bind(this)} programs={this.props.programs} />
```

The IDE successfully calls update, and when I log the output from the updateCode function in the parent, it works properly. But... In my browser component, I have the following:

```
<Button className="width-30" bsStyle="primary" onClick={() => this.props.save()}>
  <Glyphicon glyph="save" /> Save
</Button>
```

On click, it prints "", does this have to do with the fact that I bound "this" before the code in the parent state was updated? Is it just printing the old state? How can I make it update? Thanks.

Edit: I'm calling this from the IDE component: `onChange={this.props.updateCode.bind(this)}`

Comment: When you click on the button - the `save` function is being called, but there is no call for the `updateCode` function

Comment: The code is successfully updated in the other component. It contains this: `onChange={this.props.updateCode.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: I was binding the state of the CHILD in the IDE component, which meant that was what was updating, changing the implementation of the IDE component in the parent to the following: `<IDE code={this.state.code} updateCode={this.updateCode.bind(this)}/>`, allowed the states to update properly

Comment: Typically you apply the binding in the constructor: `this.updateCode = this.updateCode.bind(this);` Alternatively, you could use property initializers with an arrow function if you have the babel preset `stage-1`: `updateCode = (event) => { ... }`

Comment: By the way, did you really mean to save the "event" into the component state, instead of `event.target.value` ?